# How to remove border inside input tag when using tagsinput library in jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

How to remove border inside `<input>` tag when using `tagsinput` library in jQuery?

My problem as below:

[image]

My reference: [tagsinput bootstrap](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Something I've tried but not solve:

1. `.bootstrap-tagsinput:focus { outline: none !important; }`
2. `input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus { outline: none; }`

Code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
        <label class="col-form-label">IP Address Whitelist</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control tagsinput" id="addTokenIP" data-role="tagsinput">
        <code>Note: Please press "Enter" for every single IP entered.</code>
    </div>
</div>

$('.tagsinput').tagsinput({
    tagClass: 'badge badge-dark'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To cover all the major browsers, try this.

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
    border: 0;
    border: none;
    outline:0;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;

}
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you select the input with Chrome, right click and inspect the element?  What does it show for the CSS?

Comment: Hi, i have answer with my own solution. anyway thanks for your response. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after try and error I found the answer by applying this style.

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput > input:focus{
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, is the !important really necessary?  And, how is the input tag a child element of the the .bootstrap-tagsinput class?